# How to make ag-grid columns resizable by mouse in Angular Material

Tags: typescript, ag-grid, ag-grid-angular

In Angular 7 project, I have an ag-grid with angular material design.

How to I make the grid columns them resizable by dragging the anchor in column header like here: https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-resizing/#resizing-example

Here are my gridOptions:

```
gridOptions: GridOptions = {
  context: {
    componentParent: this
  },
  floatingFilter: false,
  pagination: true,
  paginationPageSize: 100,
  enableColResize: true,
  cacheBlockSize: 100,
  rowDeselection: true,
  rowSelection: 'multiple',
  domLayout: 'autoHeight',
  defaultColDef: {
    sortable: true,
    resizable: true,
    suppressMenu: true,
    enableRowGroup: true,
  },
  rowGroupPanelShow: 'always',
  suppressDragLeaveHidesColumns: true, // Grouping
  suppressMakeColumnVisibleAfterUnGroup: true, // Grouping
  suppressRowClickSelection: true,
  onGridReady: (params: any) => this.onGridReady(params),
  // onRowDoubleClicked: (event) => this.onRowDoubleClick(event.data),
};
```

and columDefs looks like this:

```
var colDef: ColDef = {
  field: key,
  headerName: title,
  headerTooltip: title,
  minWidth: 10,
  maxWidth: 250
};
```

Comment: what is an issue? you've tried `resizable: true` and it doesn't work?

Comment: Reproduce your issue on plunk or stackblitz and provide the link

Comment: I'm not sure what was not working, but After I finished my refactoring it is working, so I'm deleting this question

Comment: But meanwhile, maybe you could answer this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55530433/how-to-expand-the-first-group-level-in-ag-grid-angular :)