# How to expand the first group level in ag-grid-angular

Tags: ag-grid, ag-grid-angular

I have an ag-grid where rows are grouped by two columns by default, but the groups are collapsed.

```
colDefs = 
[
  {
    field: 'colA',
    rowGroupIndex: 0,
  },
  {
    field: 'colB',
    rowGroupIndex: 1
  },
  …
];
```

I would like to have the first group level expanded like this:

```
- ColA 1
  + COlB 1 (5)
  + ColB 2 (3)
- ColA 2
  + COlB 3 (1)
  + COlB 4 (9)
  + COlB 5 (11)
```

Where is the best place to expand the first level groups?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a look at the plunk I've created: **[ag-grid: expand groups in ag-grid-angular](https://plnkr.co/edit/xVREzfLjrSRUWy1OllNn?p=preview)**

```
this.gridApi.expandAll();
```

For more reference, have a look at the documentation: [Built In Menu Items](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-context-menu/#built-in-menu-items)

> expandAll: Expand all groups. Only shown if grouping by at least one column.

---

### Update:

The above point expands nodes at all levels. Below solution is to achieve as per what you need.

Have a look at the another plunk I've created: **[ag-grid: expand the first group level in ag-grid-angular](https://plnkr.co/edit/KyTfDK3ZjZg4sI69JkA5?p=preview)**

I am simply programmatically expanding the nodes which are at `0` level.

```
this.gridApi.forEachNode((node, b) => {
  if (node.level === 0) {
    node.setExpanded(true);
  }
});
```

Comment: This expands all groups (ColA, ColB), not just the first level (ColA) in my case, doesn't it?

Comment: @Liero - your issue is resolved. Check the updated answer

Answer (score 1):

in addition to Paritosh's answer:

Don't use the timeouts, there is an event called [`firstDataRendered`](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-events/#miscellaneous), which would be executed on needed time.

Comment: correct, but anyways it was expanding all nodes which PO doesn't want.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the groupDefaultExpanded option:
https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-grouping/ (I can't link directly to the section, but search for groupDefaultExpanded).  Set it to 0 for all collapsed, 1 for first level only, etc. Set to -1 to expand everything.

In your case, set it to 1 to view the items on level 1 (ie just expand the top level)

```
<ag-grid-angular [groupDefaultExpanded]="1">
</ag-grid-angular>
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option using `forEachNode` is to match on the `field` name and use `setRowNodeExpanded`.

```
gridApi.forEachNode(rowNode => {
    if (rowNode.field == 'colA')
        gridApi.setRowNodeExpanded(rowNode, true)       
});
```